# adding items to ListView using ArrayAdapter For API15 and less

Tags: android, listview

i am an intermediate in programming with android, and i wish you could help me.

i wanna add some items to the `listView` and as i read from the android developer site that to add items to the listView you should use `Adapter`.

for example i had used an `ArrayAdapter` this way:

```
    ListView lst = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listitm);
    String[] values = new String[]{"Samsung", "Archos", "Itel", "HP", "TOSHIBA", "SonY", "Google",
            "Microsoft", "Lenovo", "Acer", "Hawaii", "HTC", "LG", "etc.."};
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(String value : values){
        list.add(value);
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_main, list);

    lst.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But, when Run it on my phone the apk got crashed and when debugging it gives the error in the last statment

`lst.setAdapter(adapter);`

it gives this error at `logcat`:

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2472)
    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1250)
    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1162)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15575)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15575)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15575)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5107)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15575)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5107)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:391)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15575)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5107)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15575)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5107)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15575)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5107)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2423)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15575)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2031)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1249)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1425)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1142)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4724)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4947)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:379)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362) 
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2472) 
    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1250) 
    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1162) 
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15575) 
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617) 
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399) 
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15575) 
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617) 
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399) 
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15575) 
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5107) 
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135) 
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15575) 
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5107) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:391) 
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15575) 
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5107) 
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310) 
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15575) 
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5107) 
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396) 
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681) 
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574) 
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15575) 
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5107) 
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2423) 
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15575) 
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2031) 
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1249) 
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1425) 
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1142) 
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4724) 
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725) 
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555) 
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525) 
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4947) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805) 
                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

any help?

Comment: what is your crash? please post a log.

Comment: If it crashes then please post your logcat error trace too.

Comment: `R.layout.activity_main` for your Cell Layout seems wrong

Comment: @Buitink its the main layout which containig the listView in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try this code.Be sure it works.

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

Comment: If it still doesn't work let me know.

Comment: Thnx very much, it works fine with me, and i understanded the reason behind that